# ngdoc custom type definition

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, ngdoc

A directive i have in my project is getting large with a lot of different options

One of my parameters is called `tableFields` this object has lots of options you can add to it:

To do this ive attempted to create a `typedef` (type definition) however without luck:

```
/**
 * @typedef tableFields
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} headerTitle This string is a translate string this will be evaluated to a translate value and then translated
 * @property {Boolean} sortable  True/false value sets if the field is sortable. This will also control if the column can be searched by an external source
 * @property {Boolean} isImage True/false value if true the field will be considered as a path to an image if so the field will be converted to an image and collected from the APP server. Note that you typically do not want to sort this type of field
 * @property {String} fieldKey this key is ALWAYS required it tells the table which key to look for in the tableData object. This key / value is also the one you search for when creating searches.
 * @property {String} combineKey an extra key that allows you to bind two keys into one string
 */


/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name LBTable.directive: lbTable
 * @description
 * Wrapper for a responsive paginated table. creates a table that allows both sorting and searching.
 * Also gives the option to set custom links, callback functions and other important functions
 * @param {array} tableData The data which needs to fill the table (The array must be an array of objects)
 * @param {tableFields} tableFields object
```

Sadly when i generate my documentation it just gives me this:

[image]

So my question is how can i specify the requirements of a field or make a type definition?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: @arslan2012 sadly i did not :(

Comment: I also would like to specify a custom type I'm surprised this is not a thing